# Conditional Formatting Entire Row If Any Cell Contains Specified Text and any cell is greater than X,XXX

Tags: excel-2013

I can highlight a row, or part of a row if that row contains "Total". But additionally, I would like to check and see if total amount is greater than or less than X,XXX amount and highlight accordingly.

Comment: See: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Answer (score 0):

1. Highlight the entire sheet <sup>1</sup>
2. Use this in conditional formatting (Change `10000` to your `X,XXX`):

   ```
   =AND(COUNTIF(1:1, "total"),COUNTIF(1:1, ">="&10000))
   ```

---

[image]

> <sup>1</sup> ***Note:*** The preferred method for highlighting your entire sheet is to click the square just above the Row1 header, and to the left of the ColumnA header

This formula will count and check the number of the word `total` in a row, and also count the number of values containing `>= 10000`. If both results are more than 0, then it will highlight your row.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Also discovered that =AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Total", $C2)), $G2 <= 10000) worked very well also. I used the search method because I was using data that was sorted and sub-totaled. When sub-totals were removed, the conditional formatting was removed with it. When sub-totaled again, had to redo formatting, so search method worked best in my case.